# Match between lines while skipping pattern with Regex

Tags: python, regex

I've been trying to match between lines while skipping a pattern.
I'm using the `re.DOTALL` regex flag.

What i need to extract is

```
CHINTHAPUDI<br/>
CHINTHAPUDI<br/>
```

from between Electors Name and Father's Name.

What i have currently mustered up is this regex:

```
(?:^Elector\'s Name:.*?<br/>)(.*?)^(?:Husband|Father)
```

But it matches the other `Elector's Name` lines beneath the first match.

[Link to my regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jbbnWD/2)

Here's the document from which i want to match:

```
Elector's Name: ANANTH CHINTAPUDI<br/>
Elector's Name: THIRUPATHI <br/>
Elector's Name: SRINIVASH <br/>
CHINTHAPUDI<br/>
CHINTHAPUDI<br/>
Father's Name: POSHANNA <br/>
Father's Name: SHANKAR <br/>
Father's Name: SHANKAR <br/>
CHINTAPUDDI<br/>
CHINTHAPUDI<br/>
CHINTHAPUDI<br/>
```

How could i go about matching from the last `Elector's Name` till `Father's Name`?

Comment: Fairly simple if you remove the multiline qualifiers, and the requirement that the lines before start with `Elector's Name` and `Father` - don't have time to play with it more to keep this criteria. https://regex101.com/r/jbbnWD/3

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot! You could write it as an answer down so that i can accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option which works for your provided input:

`(?:Elector\'s Name:.*?<br/>\r?\n)+(.*?)(?:Husband|Father)`

There is one potential issue that you should consider if you use this: If an `Elector's Name` appears earlier in the document, the first set will be used. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jbbnWD/6).

Additionally, as your Regex attempt required that `Elector's Name` and `Husband` or `Father` be at the beginning of the line, here's a version which maintains that requirement. If possible, I would avoid this as it results in a much slower (30x) check.

`(?:\r?\nElector\'s Name:.*?<br/>)+\r?\n(.*?)\r?\n(?=Husband|Father)`